# Choose the right value of "K" in PAM

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, pam

I want to run the PAM in order to Clustering a Matrix of data.

But right now i haven't understood how to choose in the right way the "K" value.

Which should be the maximum number of clusters.

Last, is it correct that i have to do the PAM before the ClusGap?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

With these *heuristics* (they may fail to choose the true best k) you would usually

1. Run the clustering algorithm (k-means, PAM) several times for every k up to a maximum.
2. For every k, you keep the best by SSQ (for k-means) or TD (PAM).
3. Then you compute your heuristics statistic for every result
4. Plot the curve of the statistic
5. Depending on the heuristic, choose the knee/elbow/minimum/maximum.
6. Compare best to second best, if they are very similar, the clustering algorithm likely did not work *at all* and you may need to vary preprocessing, or try other algorithms.